# why numpy concatenate(np.concatenate) change the status of the images when concatenating two arrays of RGB images in to single array?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, concatenation

```
imgs_reshaped_d = []    
for i in xrange(total_num_images):    

         imgs_reshaped_d.append(np.expand_dims(cv2.resize(imgs_d[i],
                        (100, 200)), axis=0))
         imgs_d = np.concatenate(imgs_reshaped_d, axis=0).astype(np.float32)
```

In the above code **imgs_reshaped_d** get appened by reshaped image pixels. Then they use np.concatenate to get all the image pixels into a single array. Which gives the shape of **[num_total_images,100,200,3]**. But then I visualize single image inside the array **img_d**. It is a distorted image. Not even close to the real image I think there is a problem with this. Anyone familiar with this?

Comment: what tools do you use to visualize the image？

Comment: You should show a small sample input image, the output image, and a description of what you expect the output image to look like.

Comment: also, lots of images are 3D, but you are using them as if 2D.

Comment: @Alpha python PIL library.

Comment: Why are you expanding the dimensions of the image? its going to make imgs_d a 4D array.

Comment: @David yeah I am referring to a given code in here https://github.com/YunzhuLi/InfoGAIL/blob/master/wgail_info_0/models.py#L291

Comment: @David yeah it is useless. I remove it but results are still the same. np.cancat change the status of the image

Comment: Can you update your question with an example and some outputs, such as the shape of the arrays etc?